# Java and MySQL INSERT

Tags: java, mysql

I have set up a program for an enterprise to handle their brochures(catalogo in spanish).
I ask the user via Swings for the data, and then use it to generate a query and insert it into my db.
Here is the code:

```
                    Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                st = con.createStatement();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO `catalogos` (`id`, `name`, `keywords`) VALUES(" + catNumIn.getText() + ", '" + catNameIn.getText() + "', '" + catKeyIn.getText() +  "');";
                st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

So i would like to know what my error is. Thank you!

Comment: More detail is needed here. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Please inform us about what error it is.

Comment: Sorry for not saying, the error is that the data isnt inserted to the table

Comment: do you get an error or you just don't see the data inserted?

Comment: I dont get any errors in Java runtime but the data isnt inserted, as for what i see on phpmyadmin.

Comment: show us the stacktrace please...

Comment: You have set autoCommit to `false` but not done a commit?

Comment: I'm new to programming.. what is a stacktrace and how do i show it to you?

Comment: Also, beware of keywords `'); delete from catalogos; --`

Comment: are you catching the exception?, if yes then please write a line inside the catch ::  e.printStackTrace()



this depends if e is the exception you are catching

Comment: Yes i am catching it. It throws no error.

Comment: Also it is more safe to use prepared statement (no sql injection).
 
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO 'catalogos' ('id', 'name', 'keywords') VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

Comment: Could you display the error information?
I guess the error results from the `catalogos`. You may try to get rid of the single quote,just use catalogos.

Answer (score 2):

Are you committing your transaction? You've said `setAutoCommit(false)` after all. Could you try:

```
setAutoCommit(true);
```

instead of the line you currently have, or:

```
con.commit();
```

after your database update?

Comment: As i said i'm quite new to programming. Could you tell me what a commit is?I don't know what it is so I don't know if it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you construct sql statement in your front end and have an error, the best approach is to print the variable and see if there is a problem with the values like single quotes,missing comma,etc